# Задача Time Difference.Java. Проблемы с преобразованием времени

Tags: java

Доброго времени суток господа, решаю задачу о преобразовании времени. Суть в том что дается 2 даты в виде дни/часы/минуты/секунды. Вторая дата позже по времени, нужно преобразовать обе даты нужно перевести в секунды, чтобы узнать разницу между ними. В секунды перевел, посчитал, теперь пытаюсь результат(большое число, количество секунд) перевести обратно в требуемый формат дни/часы/минуты/секунды. Вот код(пусть вас не пугает количество сканеров, я числа с клавиатуры ввожу)

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter count of numbers: ");
    int d = scanner.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < d; i++) {
        int a = scanner.nextInt();
        int b = scanner.nextInt();
        int c = scanner.nextInt();
        int e = scanner.nextInt();
        int a1 = scanner.nextInt();
        int b1 = scanner.nextInt();
        int c1 = scanner.nextInt();
        int e1 = scanner.nextInt();

        int res = a*86400 + b * 3600 + c * 60+ e;
        int  res1 = a1*86400+ b1 * 3600 + c1 * 60+ e1;
        int resultTime = res1 - res;


        int days = resultTime / 86400;
        int hours = resultTime / 3600;
        int minutes = resultTime / 60;
        int seconds = resultTime % 60;

        System.out.print("("+days+" "+hours+" "+minutes+" "+seconds + ")" + " ");

    }
}
```

}

Самое интересное то, что у меня каким-то образом считаются верно дни и секунды, а вот с минутами и часами получается нечто совершенно невразумительное. Прошу помочь тех, кто дружил в школе с математикой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int days = resultTime / 86400;
resultTime -= days*86400
int hours = resultTime / 3600;
resultTime -= hours*3600
```

Comment: задачу решил, решение ваше помогло. Можно пару комментариев, для осознания проблемы, почему у меня дни и секунды были верными а остальное нет?

Comment: часы у вас считаются абсолютными, без учёта посчитанных дней. та же проблема с минутами